# How I can add multiple textField in a single Loop?

Tags: iphone, ios, textfield

I wants add multiple UITextFields in a single loop. And  identify them  when user interact with UITextFields . So please help me.

Thanks

Currently I place UITextField Individually, like this

```
txt_FirstName=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(framex1, framey1, framex2, framey2)];
txt_FirstName.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
txt_FirstName.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
txt_FirstName.placeholder = @"First Name";
txt_FirstName.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
txt_FirstName.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
txt_FirstName.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
txt_FirstName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
txt_FirstName.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
txt_FirstName.delegate = self;
[frameView addSubview:txt_FirstName];
[txt_FirstName release];

framey1=framey1+50;

txt_MiddleName=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(framex1, framey1, framex2, framey2)];
txt_MiddleName.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
txt_MiddleName.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
txt_MiddleName.placeholder = @"Middle Name";
txt_MiddleName.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
txt_MiddleName.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
txt_MiddleName.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
txt_MiddleName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
txt_MiddleName.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
txt_MiddleName.delegate = self;
[frameView addSubview:txt_MiddleName];
[txt_MiddleName release];
```

Comment: May I ask why you are not using nib file and IB?

Comment: Yeah tia is right.. Please use XIB file instead of code.. It will be very simple for you..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use this, but Implement UITextField delegate in your .h file. but You should have to change your place holder according to your requirement like 1 for FirstName, 2 for MiddleName etc.

First create common function like this,

```
-(void)setTextfieldStyle:(UITextField *)pTmpTextField
{
        pTmpTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        pTmpTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        pTmpTextField.placeholder = @"First Name";
        pTmpTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        pTmpTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        pTmpTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        pTmpTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        pTmpTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
        pTmpTextField.delegate = self;
}
```

and use this for creating UITextFiled,

```
int y = 0;
for(int i=0;i < 5;i++)
{
    UITextField *txtTemp=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, 300, 31)];
    txtTemp.tag = i;
    [self setTextfieldStyle:txtTemp];
    [self.view addSubview:txtTemp];
    [txtTemp release];
    y+=36;
}
```

This is UITextField's delegate method,

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);
}
```

Hope this works for you..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set attributes of a bunch of text fields in a loop, you could also do something like:

```
NSMutableArray* allTextFields = [NSMutableArray array];

// create the textFields here, I'm assuming you need to keep individual
// references to them.
txt_FirstName=[[UITextField alloc]init];
pTmpTextField.placeholder = @"First Name";
[allTextFields addObject:txt_FirstName];

// now add the common style stuff and frame
[allTextFields enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UITextField* textField, NSUInteger idx, BOOL* stop) {
    textField.frame = CGRectMake(framex1, framey1 + ( 50 * idx), framex2, framey2);
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    textField.placeholder = @"First Name";
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
    textField.delegate = self;
}];
```